# how to get a window to receive drag and drop files in Xcode

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nswindow

i am trying to get drag and drop working in xcode 3.1.4 on osx/leopard. any pointers or hints or maybe even example code? i cannot find anything out there and it is really disappointing.
i want to have the interface respond if files are dragged on the main window.

Comment: As you didn't tell us which framework you are using, I assumed you are working with Cocoa. I re-tagged your question to reach a broader audience. (Most people check the "Cocoa" tag when searching for Mac OS X programming questions)

Comment: More to the point, most people check the Cocoa tag when looking for Cocoa questions to answer, and the IDE you're using (Xcode) is quite irrelevant to the solution, which involves the *framework* you're using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To register a window or view as a dragging destination, use the [registerForDraggedTypes:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483578-registerfordraggedtypes:) method of NSWindow or NSView.
You can find further details in the [Getting Started with Drag and Drop Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html) guide on developer.apple.com

Comment: thanks! this is a very good answer, since this also applicable for mac osx leopard. i could only find snow leopard examples and they are fundamentally different!